# SignalR integration for ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working on an ASP.NET Boilerplate project. I want to integrate SignalR properly to this project.

There is the documentation, but I want to know the flow of SignalR, when sending notifications from the back-end to the front-end. Any sample code or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET Boilerplate is open-source, so you can look at the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate).

From the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration#notification): **Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR** package implements **IRealTimeNotifier**.

The code below is for ASP.NET Core & jQuery version, but the flow is the same for other versions.

1. On the back-end, `NotificationDistributer` injects and [calls](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/80576e4f3b6ca8c6279a742b55f78268eae372d8/src/Abp/Notifications/NotificationDistributer.cs#L59) `IRealTimeNotifier`:

   ```cs
   await RealTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(userNotifications.ToArray());
   ```
2. `SignalRRealTimeNotifier` [implements](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/430423983fffe1aff0d92e93f8b6bbc8841cd41d/src/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR/AspNetCore/SignalR/Notifications/SignalRRealTimeNotifier.cs#L39) `SendNotificationsAsync`, which gets the online clients for each user and invokes the client-side method with the `userNotification` as a parameter:

   ```cs
   var onlineClients = _onlineClientManager.GetAllByUserId(userNotification);
   foreach (var onlineClient in onlineClients)
   {
       var signalRClient = _hubContext.Clients.Client(onlineClient.ConnectionId);
       signalRClient.InvokeAsync("getNotification", userNotification);
   }
   ```
3. The SignalR client [registers](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/7b70d4057be02d1a17b50f145a9b5a395ca5a95c/src/Abp.Web.Resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.signalr-client.js#L38-L41) for `getNotification` and triggers `'abp.notifications.received'` with the `notification` as a parameter:

   ```js
   connection.on('getNotification', function (notification) {
       abp.event.trigger('abp.notifications.received', notification);
   });
   ```
4. The [module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template) has **main.js** that [registers](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/ad26a02d60ee37cb36f3acb6387b35492f7c8c0a/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/js/main.js#L3-L5) a notification handler:

   ```js
   abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function (userNotification) {
       abp.notifications.showUiNotifyForUserNotification(userNotification);
   }
   ```
5. `showUiNotifyForUserNotification` [formats and shows](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/bf0106d3f29256f5203321e9a5d1f74a8bfd98c5/src/Abp.Web.Resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js#L320-L324) the notification on the front-end:

   ```js
   abp.notifications.showUiNotifyForUserNotification = function (userNotification, options) {
       var message = abp.notifications.getFormattedMessageFromUserNotification(userNotification);
       var uiNotifyFunc = abp.notifications.getUiNotifyFuncBySeverity(userNotification.notification.severity);
       uiNotifyFunc(message, undefined, options);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution aaron. This should work.